# Can we add a panel in other panel? If yes, then what's wrong in my code

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make a very simple Time Manager, when i compile it shows an error. I am unable to find the mistake in my code which is producing the error.

```
JPanel otherPanel = new JPanel();
otherPanel.add(BorderLayout.WEST, timingsPanel);
otherPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, todoPanel);
otherPanel.add(BorderLayout.EAST, checkPanel);
```

The error is:

```
Error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:460)
    at GUI.setUpGui(GUI.java:57) at manager.main(manager.java:6)
```

code around line 57:

```
//setting up otherstuff
otherPanel = new JPanel();
otherPanel.add(BorderLayout.WEST, timingsPanel);
otherPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, todoPanel);
otherPanel.add(BorderLayout.EAST, checkPanel);
```

The below code in minimum, it's also showing the same error

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class timeclass
{
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel headerPanel;
    JLabel header;
    JPanel otherPanel;
    JPanel timingsPanel;
    JPanel todoPanel;
    JPanel checkPanel;


    public void setUpGui()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Time Manager");

        //setting up header
        headerPanel = new JPanel();
        header = new JLabel("Time Manager");
        header.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 36));
        headerPanel.add(header);

        //setting up otherstuff
        otherPanel = new JPanel();
        otherPanel.add(BorderLayout.WEST, timingsPanel);
        otherPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, todoPanel);
        otherPanel.add(BorderLayout.EAST, checkPanel);

        //setting up frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BoxLayout boxLayout4 = new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        frame.setLayout(boxLayout4);
        frame.add(headerPanel);
        frame.add(otherPanel);
        frame.setSize(900, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1117)
 at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:460)
 at GUI.setUpGui(GUI.java:57)
 at manager.main(manager.java:6)

Comment: One of `timingsPanel`, `todoPanel` or `checkPanel` is `null`.

Comment: I would say one of the panels you are trying to add wasn't initialized and your variable is NULL

Comment: It seems that you forgot to create some panel... Please, take a look here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Whenever  you get an NPE, start looking and printing out values to see if they have been properly initialized.  It's usually much faster than waiting for help.

Comment: what do you mean by, one of the panel is null?

Comment: no panel is null

Comment: everything seems correct, but can't find the error

Comment: Why not post the code around line 57 (or even more).

Comment: code around line 57:

Comment: The error could be anywhere.  We're not going to be able to find it just by looking at these four lines of code.  Can you produce a minimal example that shows the error?

Comment: Can you use debugging to see the values of the panels?

Comment: i've added the minimum code producing the same error

Comment: Your error is in the `manager.main`, not `timeclass`

Comment: There was dedicated post with houndreds of upvotes as standard "this is duplication" flag that explains "what is nullpointerexception and how to fix it" but for whatever reasons i cannot find that on stackoverflow now.

Comment: Ahh got it https://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/1527544

Comment: The `otherPanel.add(BorderLayout.WEST, timingsPanel);`  construct has been obsolete since Java1.1..